# What does socket binding mean?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

In https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html, the socket.bind(address) entry says:

> Bind the socket to address. The socket must not already be bound. (The format of address depends on the address family — see above.)

That is all it says, what does "Bind the socket to address" mean?

Comment: There's a "too long, didn't read" candidate here about the subject: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs50/socketprogramming.html If you're bored, you could take a look to it **:-)**

Answer (score 3):

It's basically just assigning an address to it so you can accept incoming connections on that address. Have a look at: [man bind](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

It just means that after also calling `listen()` and when using the `accept()` method, it will be listening for requests to connect to that particular address.